# Can Cavalieri's Principle be applied to a Pyramid and a Cylinder?

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

I know that Cavalieri's Principle makes it so that if two prisms/cylinders, or two pyramids/cones have the same area at a cross section parallel to the base, and they have the same height, they also have the same volume. However, does it still apply to a pyramid/cone and a prism/cylinder?

Research:
All examples of Cavalieri's Principle show two prisms/cylinders *or* two pyramids/cones. They never get mixed. I have found that on [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CavalierisPrinciple.html) it is defined as "...the same distance from their respective bases are always equal..." implying that a cone and a prism wouldn't fall under this since the prism's cross-section would remain constant, but the cone's would increase or decrease based on height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, if we're comparing a solid with constant cross-sectional area to one whose cross sectional area vanishes as we move away from its base, then Cavalieri's Principle is inapplicable. Put another way, a pyramid/cone might have the same volume and height as a prism/cylinder, but even in such a case, they cannot have equal cross-sectional areas throughout.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to explain this to my geometry teacher, but she is just refering me back to Cavalieri's principle. The example stated in the textbook never talks about mixing cones and cylinders, but the question did.

Comment: What was the question, exactly? It might be that you can reorient them to use different "bases" and "heights," I suppose.

Comment: The question stated that the cross-section of a cylinder (prism-ish) and a pyramid were equal and that their heights were equal. It was implied that the cross sections were parallel to the base. The answer options were the ratios of the two volumes: 1:1, 1:2, 2:1, or other. I assumed that the cross-section was at the bottom, in which case a pyramid (Bh/3) is 1/3 of a prism (Bh). I chose "other" since the ratio was 1:3, but depending on where you made the cross section, the ratios differed, making all answers technically correct. I called the people who make the quiz and it is a known error. TX

Answer (score 0):

Cavalieri's principle is an intuitive way of describing Fubini's theorem on multivariate integrals. Archimedes has done marvelous things with it, e.g., a derivation of the volume formula for a sphere using a sphere, a cylinder, and a cone in a unique argument. See the first example here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle